# Wait until user presses enter in C++?

Tags: c++, windows, linux, cin, enter

```
waitForEnter() {
    char enter;

    do {
        cin.get(enter);
    } while ( enter != '\n' );
}
```

It works, but not always. It doesn't work when an enter is pressed just before the function is called.

Comment: What platform(s) are you targeting?  Unbuffered input is likely platform-specific.

Comment: You cannot do this easily and portabley - most of the other answer will work most of the time

Comment: Using standard input for this is wrong.  Don't be afraid to use platform specific keyboard routines.

Comment: I'm working on Linux now but it has to work on both Linux and Windows.

Comment: Look at [GetAsyncKeyState](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646293%28v=vs.85%29.aspx?ppud=4) for Windows.  Perhaps someone else can provide the appropriate Linux function.

Comment: Ah it didn't work in the one case, because I used cin >> instead of cin.get(), I see now.

Comment: With linux you could use the `ncurses` library. But I don't understand what you really want to do!

Answer (score 2):

You can use `getline` to make the program wait for any newline-terminated input:

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <limits>

void wait_once()
{
  std::string s;
  std::getline(std::cin, s);
}
```

In general, you cannot simply "clear" the entire input buffer and ensure that this call will always block. If you *know* that there's previous input that you want to discard, you can add `std::cin.ignore(std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(), '\n');` above the `getline` to gobble up any left-over characters. However, if there was no extra input to begin with, this will cause an additional pause.

If you want full control over the console and the keyboard, you may have to look at a platform-specific solution, for instance, a terminal library like `ncurses`.

A `select` call on a Posix system that can tell you if reading from a file descriptor would block, so there you could write the function as follows:

```
#include <sys/select.h>

void wait_clearall()
{
  fd_set p;
  FD_ZERO(&p);
  FD_SET(0, &p);

  timeval t;
  t.tv_sec = t.tv_usec = 0;

  int sr;

  while ((sr = select(1, &p, NULL, NULL, &t)) > 0)
  {
    char buf[1000];
    read(0, buf, 1000);
  }
}
```

Comment: @Cubbi: Yeah. Somehow no matter what you do, you can't really prevent someone from queuing up a ton of newlines in the buffer.

Comment: As I was typing up my answer on this iPhone, I already thought that you'd be the one to answer before me. Though, I also thought we'd have the same answer. :P

Comment: Also, I'd use `streamsize` instead of `size_t`, though I think it's just a typedef of the same unsigned integer.

Comment: @Xeo: yes, I was lazy. Your answer is way tidier :-) Anyway, how about `ignore`ing *all* characters, not just up to `\n`?

Comment: @Xeo: No, ignoring everything is also no good because it will actually go and read all those characters -- it's not a maximum. I think `readsome` is the way to go!

Comment: Hm, `readsome` is also not doing the right thing. I'm beginning to suspect that we may need something based on `select` or so. This is a platform-dependent problem that won't have a C++ answer.

Comment: I think platform specific is correct, simplest way is to just capture the actual Enter keypress rather than the input from it.

Comment: @Xeo: Well, maybe we can do a little better than that. Cooked input is OK, but you have to determine when there's anything left to be read. I think `select` can tell you that...

Comment: The thing with `ignore` is that you can use `gcount()` to check if you *did* gobble any data, but you cannot tell when there's *nothing* to be read and the call will block. Basically, there's no way to tell in general if the next call will block.

Comment: Then I'll leave this question to you, since I really gotta go to sleep (5am here), and I don't really know about `select`... have fun. :)

Comment: Hm, I have to go, too. I'll edit the answer, though to make it a bit clearer.

Comment: @Xeo: `select`-solution added!

Answer (score 1):

On Windows, you can do this:

```
void WaitForEnter()
{
    // if enter is already pressed, wait for
    // it to be released
    while (GetAsyncKeyState(VK_RETURN) & 0x8000) {}

    // wait for enter to be pressed
    while (!(GetAsyncKeyState(VK_RETURN) & 0x8000)) {}
}
```

I don't know the equivalent on Linux.

Answer (score 0):

(the first parameter) The name of the array of type `char[]` in which the characters read from `cin` are to be stored.

(the second parameter) The maximum number of characters to be read. When the specified maximum has been read, input stops.

(the third parameter) The character that is to stop the input process. You can specify any character here, and the first occurrence of that character will stop the input process.

```
cin.getline( name , MAX, ‘\n’ );
```

Page 175 IVOR HORTON’S *BEGINNING VISUAL C++® 2010*