# How do I clean input buffer before using getch()?

Tags: c++, winapi, getch, bgi, winbgi

So, I am using GetAsyncKeyState() to see when some key is pressed. But, after using it I need to use getch(). But it seems that getch() gets whatever GetAsyncKeyState() got before again. That is the version of my simplified code:

```
#include <graphics.h>

int main()
{
    initwindow(100, 100);

    while(true)
    {        
        if (GetAsyncKeyState(VK_RETURN))    //wait for user to press "Enter"
            break;
        //do other stuff
    }

    getch();    //this is just skipped

    return 0;
}
```

I think I need to clean the input buffer before using getch(). But how?
PS: GetAsyncKeyState() is a must-use for me and I have not found any substitute for getch(), which could work with BGI window and which would fix the problem.
Hoping for some advice and thank you.

Answer (score 3):

Use [`FlushConsoleInputBuffer`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms683147%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

```
FlushConsoleInputBuffer(GetStdHandle(STD_INPUT_HANDLE));
```

Comment: I do not know what I am doing wrong, but it still skips getch. Can the fact that I am working with bgi graphics window be the case? Thanks for your answer.

Comment: @user3496846: Could be. I'm not familiar with bgi graphics. I assumed `getch` was the same as the one from the WINAPI, in which case, this should work. Apparently it's not. What behavior are you trying to get from `getch`? You may be able to simulate it entirely with WINAPI functions. For example, see this answer of mine from another question: http://stackoverflow.com/a/8177635/440119

Comment: What I want to do is to read a char from the keyboard without the need for the console window to be active (in my case the BGI window is active). And I do not want the char to be the code of the "Enter" key, which is happening right now. Is there a way to read a char with a WINAPI function? Thank you for you help.

Answer (score 0):

It is skipping `getch()` call beacuse of `enter` pressed by user for the previous input, and `getch` is getting that `char`, the function `fflush(stdin)` we flush the input stream. 
so that `getch()` will read the fresh input from input stream.

```
#include <graphics.h>

int main()
{
    initwindow(100, 100);

    while(true)
    {        
        if (GetAsyncKeyState(VK_RETURN))    //wait for user to press "Enter"
            break;
        //do other stuff
    }
    fflush(stdin);
    getch();    //this is just skipped

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Sorry, but it does not seem to work. Even when I put Sleep(1000) right before fflush, the application still skips getch.